# In what order prerequisites will be made by the GNU make?

Tags: dependencies, makefile, gnu

Assuming we have the rule:

```
a: b c d e
```

and `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` are independent of each other.

Is the order of making `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` defined? It seems that generally they will be made in order `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, but may it sometimes happen, that the order will be different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, if I use `make -j a`, they might all get built at the same time (depending on whether `b`, `c`, `d`, or `e` in turn have other/interrelated dependencies).

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question so I'm surprised it was accepted.

Comment: The question I read there is "It seems that generally they will be made in order `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, but may it sometimes happen, that the order will be different?".  I'm pretty sure I provided a counterexample.  Your opinion may vary, I suppose.

Comment: *order-only-prerequisites* **are** built in a particular order. I'm not sure the poster knew there was anything other than *normal-prerequisites* based on his assumption, though.

Comment: @jww no, order-only-prerequisites are not build in a particular order, they just don't **"[..] force the target to be updated if one of those rules is executed [..]"**.

Comment: @user181548, don't be surprised, this is very typical SO behavior.

Answer (score 38):

No, the order is not defined. That is the whole *point* in using declarative dependency-oriented programming: that the computer can pick the optimal evaluation order, or in fact, evaluate them even *at the same time*.

Comment: in 2016, _GNU make_'s maintainer described the order as at least "known"/deterministic (though apparently just for some cases). Details and some elaborations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77176584/1562596

Answer (score 15):

> In what order prerequisites will be made by the GNU make?

It depends on the type of the prerequisite. According tho the [GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.pdf), Section 4.2:

> There are actually two different types of prerequisites understood by
>   GNU make: normal prerequisites such as described in the previous
>   section, and order-only prerequisites. A normal prerequisite makes two
>   statements: first, it imposes an order in which recipes will be
>   invoked: the recipes for all prerequisites of a target will be
>   completed before the recipe for the target is run. Second, it imposes
>   a dependency relationship: if any prerequisite is newer than the
>   target, then the target is considered out-of-date and must be rebuilt.
>
> Normally, this is exactly what you want: if a target’s prerequisite is
>   updated, then the target should also be updated.
>
> Occasionally, however, you have a situation where you want to impose a
>   specific ordering on the rules to be invoked *without* forcing the
>   target to be updated if one of those rules is executed. In that case,
>   you want to define *order-only* prerequisites. Order-only
>   prerequisites can be specified by placing a pipe symbol (|) in the
>   prerequisites list: any prerequisites to the left of the pipe symbol
>   are normal; any prerequisites to the right are order-only:
>
> ```
>    targets: normal-prerequisites | order-only-prerequisites
> ```
>
> The normal prerequisites section may of course be empty. Also, you may
>   still declare multiple lines of prerequisites for the same target:
>   they are appended appropriately (normal prerequisites are appended to
>   the list of normal prerequisites; order-only prerequisites are
>   appended to the list of order-only prerequisites). Note that if you
>   declare the same file to be both a normal and an order-only
>   prerequisite, the normal prerequisite takes precedence (since they
>   have a strict superset of the behavior of an order-only prerequisite).
>
> Consider an example where your targets are to be placed in a separate
>   directory, and that directory might not exist before `make` is run. In
>   this situation, you want the directory to be created before any
>   targets are placed into it but, because the timestamps on directories
>   change whenever a file is added, removed, or renamed, we certainly
>   don’t want to rebuild all the targets whenever the directory’s
>   timestamp changes. One way to manage this is with order-only
>   prerequisites: make the directory an order-only prerequisite on all
>   the targets:
>
> ```
> OBJDIR := objdir
> OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,foo.o bar.o baz.o)
>
> $(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
>     $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
>
> all: $(OBJS)
>
> $(OBJS): | $(OBJDIR)
>
> $(OBJDIR):
>     mkdir $(OBJDIR)
> ```
>
> Now the rule to create the ‘objdir’ directory will be run, if needed,
>   before any ‘.o’ is built, but no ‘.o’ will be built because the
>   ‘objdir’ directory timestamp changed.

Comment: This doesn't really impose an ordering though, at least not any more than a normal prerequisite. It just says that for an order-only prerequisite gmake should ignore the timestamp. It is a prerequisite, so it has to exist before the current rule can be run, but since it is an order-only prerequisite its timestamp/state does not trigger the current rule. (Which does not rule out other dependencies causing the order-only dependencies from executing their commands.)

Comment: From the gnu make documentation above: `Occasionally, however, you have a situation where you want to impose a specific ordering on how the rules of a target are going to be invoked without forcing the target to be updated if one of those rules is executed.`  This seems rather bad-worded for what the oder-only prerequisite really does. Up to my understanding a order-only prerequisite is simply a prerequisites which does not force `make` to rebuild the target if  it changes.

Comment: I think this is not what the OP was searching for. Try invoking `make -j` to find out whether dependencies are really executed in the order you expect.

Answer (score 7):

In the *right* order, based on the rules you provide. For your particular example, that could mean any one of a number of different (4! = 24, from memory) orders.

All `make` programs are free to choose the order they like as long as the dependencies are honored. If there were other rules in your example, say `c: b`, then `c` would be made before `b` (but that isn't the case, as you point out).

If you need to rely on a specific order, you'll need more rules to enforce it. Otherwise `make` can do what it pleases. The [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) for GNU Make only states how *rules* are processed, not the order in which dependencies within a rule are processed. The most logical order (to me, anyway) would be the order in which they're listed but that's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't count on the ordering when there are no dependency relationships.

- make needs to do [a topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort), because dependencies may have additional and multiple relationships. The sort that make does is potentially quite complex, as nodes in the graph may be related multiple times at different levels
- in general sorting algorithms are not naturally [*stable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_sort#Stability), even for simple key-based sorts

Answer (score 4):

I'll just add this for future reference. While GNU Make may not define a specific order when it comes to processing prerequisites, POSIX make requires that they be handled in the order they've been specified, namely left-to-right. Most implementations follow this rule. POSIX even gives an example where a make implementation not following this rule could break the build process of a program:

```
foo: y.tab.o lex.o main.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ t.tab.o lex.o main.o
```

where lex.o ends up using an incorrect y.tab.h. While this can be rewritten in a way that works with GNU Make, I thought I'd share this tidbit about prerequisite ordering.

Comment: Source: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/make.html#tag_04_84_13_03

Answer (score 2):

If order matters, you can selectively enforce it using [recursive make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recursion.html). For example, suppose you don't care what order b and c are made in, as long as they're both made before d and d is made before e. Then you could write your rule as:

```
a: b c
    $(MAKE) d
    $(MAKE) e
    # Additional steps to make a
```

Be aware that depending on the complexity of d and e, this approach may do Bad Things to your build times: see [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf) (PDF) for arguments against doing it this way.