# Order of processing components in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In a makefile, the dependency line is of the form -

```
abc: x y z
```

All three of the components (x,y,z) are themselves targets in dependency lines further down in the makefile.

If *make abc* is invoked, in what order will the three targets x,y,z be executed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In what order prerequisites will be made by the GNU make?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647480/in-what-order-prerequisites-will-be-made-by-the-gnu-make)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

By default, the order of execution is the same as specified in the prerequisites list, unless there are any dependencies defined between these prerequisites.

```
abc: x y z
```

The order is `x y z`.

```
abc: x y z
y : z
```

The order would be `x z y`.

But ideally, you should design your Makefiles so that it wouldn't rely on the order in which prerequisites are specified. That is, if `y` should be executed after `z`, there **must be** a `y : z` dependence.

And keep in mind that GNU Make can execute some recipes in parallel, see [Mat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9160175/545027).

Comment: @Shailesh, you're welcome. I've added and UPD. section after posting the main answer.

Comment: @EldarAbusalimov: No need for that - there is a revision history. Just make the answer a single, cohesive piece of prose.

Comment: -1. It's not "by default", it's just undefined. It will work like this until it doesn't because you changed something unrelated.

Answer (score 59):

You really shouldn't depend on the order in which they are executed - all else being equal, all three recipes for those prerequisites could run in parallel.

The only hard rule is that all prerequisites must be met before the target recipe is run.

If there are no dependencies between `x`, `y` and `z`, and no parallel execution, GNU make appears to run them in the order you specified them, but this is not guaranteed in the docs.

Comment: Short and clear answer. I can't `+1` right now, but I'll try not to forget to come back and vote up tomorrow.

Comment: Another way of putting this: whenever there *is* an order dependency, make it explicit as a Makefile rule.

Comment: 'recipe' is the term used to denote the list of commands under a dependency line?

Comment: Yes, that's the term (in the GNU make documentation anyway).

Answer (score 22):

The POSIX description of [`make`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html) includes a rationale which says:

> The `make` utilities in most historical implementations process the prerequisites of a target in left-to-right order, and the makefile format requires this. It supports the standard idiom used in many makefiles that produce `yacc` programs; for example:
>
> ```
> foo: y.tab.o lex.o main.o
>      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ t.tab.o lex.o main.o
> ```
>
> In this example, if `make` chose any arbitrary order, the `lex.o` might not be made with the correct `y.tab.h`. Although there may be better ways to express this relationship, it is widely used historically. Implementations that desire to update prerequisites in parallel should require an explicit extension to `make` or the makefile format to accomplish it, as described previously.

(*I believe the `t.tab.o` in the `$(CC)` line is a typo for `y.tab.o`, but that is what the rationale actually says.*)

Thus, the observed behaviour that pre-requisites are processed from left to right has validation here, though it is only in the Rationale section, not in the main description.  The Rationale also mentions issues with parallel `make` etc.

Comment: +1 for POSIX description and the important caveat about parallel `make` jobs. IMO the choice not to allow enforcement of any order on parallel jobs was a misstep. _e.g._ I am happy for my `.o`bjects to be compiled in any order, but I need a bunch of other things to happen before and after compiling and linking respectively, and it's a lot more difficult than it should be...

Comment: I'll point out that GNU make diverges pretty significantly from POSIX make, and the `.POSIX` special target should be included in the makefile to signal that it should behave in a compatible way.

Answer (score 0):

New to GNU make 4.4, we have the `.WAIT` prerequisite!

Set it as a dependency, and it will pause all dependencies to the *right* of it until all the ones to the *left* are completed.

```
all: please_run_me and_me .WAIT before_me
```

Note that `please_run_me` & `and_me` are not ordered in relation to eachother, but both will finish before `before_me` starts.

You can throw multiple `.WAIT`s on a line.

There was another way added to do this too - `.NOTPARALLEL`, you can read about it [in the changelog](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-make/2022-10/msg00020.html) or [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel-Disable.html)

---

Though it released on the 31st October 2022, some distributions (e.g.: Ubuntu) may not come with it preinstalled yet.

If you want to install `make` for such devices, you'll have to build from source.

Answer (score -5):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/22638294/636849, you can add the pipe symbol:

```
abc: | x y z
```

> From make manual: 
>   Order-only prerequisites can be specified by placing a pipe symbol (|) in the prerequisites list: any prerequisites to the left of the pipe symbol are normal; any prerequisites to the right are order-only:
>
> targets : normal-prerequisites | order-only-prerequisites

Comment: No, that's not what order-only prerequisites do.  `foo: | bar baz` does not enforce `bar baz` any more than without the pipe character.  Instead, the pipe says roughly "when ordering foo, bar and baz, bar and baz must both come before foo, but updates to bar and baz are not sufficient reason to cause foo to be considered updated and to need to run".

Docs are at https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html and are not the clearest.

Comment: @PhilP I'm not a native speaker, but I would suggest that "consider OUTdated" (and thus to need to run) is what you meant, no?

Comment: I can't edit it to fix, but yes you are right.  I think I reworded a couple of times and lost something.  "to be considered as needing updates" works too.  Thank you.