# Why is make running a recipe before its prerequisites?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a make file with some pattern rules¹ that end up as prerequisites for another rule. A minimum example that shows the symptoms I'm puzzled by is this:

```
.PHONY: clean default one two

default: clean one two

clean:
    @rm -f {one,two}.{a,b}

one two: %: %.a %.b
    @echo TARGET $@ PREREQUISITES $^

%.a %.b:
    @echo Prereq $@
    @touch $@
```

The output I expect when running this would be:

> Prereq one.a
>   Prereq one.b
>   TARGET one PREREQUISITES one.a one.b
>   Prereq two.a
>   Prereq two.b
>   TARGET two PREREQUISITES two.a two.b

Instead, only the first prerequisite gets built, `make` gives me this:

> Prereq one.a
>   TARGET one PREREQUISITES one.a one.b
>   Prereq two.a
>   TARGET two PREREQUISITES two.a two.b

As you can see, the recipe itself parses these correctly and knows that it should have been built after both prerequisites, but the prerequisite rule hasn't actually been run.

Incidentally, I'm using order-only prerequisites for the second item here but it doesn't really matter: the same problem is exhibited either way.

If I run the same target a second time, then it builds the second prerequisite. In other words two passes finally gets me the result I need:

```
$ make clean
$ make one
Prereq one.a
TARGET one PREREQUISITES one.a one.b
$ make one
Prereq one.b
TARGET one PREREQUISITES one.a one.b
```

The first time it runs, only the first prerequisite exists and I'm left with a broken `one`. On the second pass `one.a` exists, so it decides to build `one.b`. Now that both prerequisites exist my `one` builds properly.

If I spell out the prerequisite target variations as two separate recipes (repeat the same block for both `%a:` and `%.b` patterns separately) then both prerequisites get built for each target. However this would make my file quite a bit more complex and I'd like to understand why this breaks.

---

¹ <sub>This make file has some [other problems](/q/41681784) but I've isolated this issue to an reproducible case so I don't think its other idiosyncrasies are the issue here.</sub>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order-only prerequisites not working correctly in GNU make?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821611/order-only-prerequisites-not-working-correctly-in-gnu-make)

Comment: @giusti This is note an order-only prerequisite problem. The exact same results turn up normal dependencies only.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNU Make has what we may consider a little "quirk" in the sense that multiple-target pattern rules don't work exactly like several rules. In this situation, the rule is triggered only once by a single target, and Make expects the rule to make all targets at once. From the [GNU Make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Intro):

> Pattern rules may have more than one target. Unlike normal rules, this does not act as many different rules with the same prerequisites and recipe. If a pattern rule has multiple targets, make knows that the rule’s recipe is responsible for making all of the targets. The recipe is executed only once to make all the targets. [...]

So what is happening here is:

1. checks the dependencies for `one`: finds `one.a` and `one.b` from the pattern `%: %.a %.b`;
2. finds one pattern rule for both `one.a` and `one.b`;
3. executes the recipe with target (`$@`) set to `one.a` (the one that triggered the rule);
4. marks both `one.a` and `one.b` as updated, even though the recipe only created `one.a`;
5. thinks all depencies for `one` have been satisfied and go on to do the same with `two`.

The reason why Make touches different files when you call it again is because now `one.a` and `two.a` are up-to-date. So the targets that trigger the rule become `one.b` and `two.b`. If you remove only `one.a` before calling Make a second time, it will create `one.a` and `two.b`.

So you have at least three possible solutions. One is to spell out the targets that behave like you'd expects—which you said is not a good solution, but it's worth mentioning here anyway. Another is to break that `%.a %.b` into two rules, which achieves the same but might be easier considering your needs. And the third is to do what Make expects and create both targets in the same recipe—*e.g.*, you can use the stem in the recipe:

```
%.a %.b:
        @echo Processing target $@ from stem $*
        touch $*.a $*.b
```

Another thing that I noticed while looking into this problem is that your MCVE's `clean` is broken. By default, Make will use `/bin/sh`, which will not expand things like `{a,b}`. You can set `SHELL=/bin/bash` to change that.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I understand the 1st and 3rd options you suggest. The 1st is doable but obnoxious because it's a huge recipe with a lot of logic I'd rather not repeat. The 3rd is pretty much impossible because some make runs will generate one and not the other while some will  do both (there are test & CI & deploy things involved here). Not all the runs will be capable of supplying the prerequisites for both a and b. I don't understand your second option at all. How is that an not the same thing as the first option.

Comment: To avoid repeating yourself just put the recipe into a multi-line variable using `define` ... `endef` and then you can use that variable in the recipe of all the rules, instead of writing it all out multiple times.

Comment: The first suggestion is `one.a one.b two.a two.b:`. If you want to extend to `three.a` and `three.b`, you need to spell them out as targets too. The second is one rule for `%.a` and another for `%.b`. You don't need to modify anything to extend for `three.{a,b}`. Of course, if you have a rule that depends on `one.a`  and `two.a` you'll run into the same problem again. So that suggestion is only suitable if you can ensure that `prefix%suffix` will match only one dependency per target and rule.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. I miss-understood your first option. In my case I can actually do that since I can programatically generate a list of all possible permutations. Sadly I've discovered this doesn't actually resolve the issue like my MWE suggests it would. I have the same problem in a project that _doesn't_ have multiple patterns (i.e. just `%.a:` not `%.a %.b`). Providing a full list of fixed names didn't solve this either, I'm _still_ encountering the target recipe running before it's prerequisites!

Comment: That's interesting. Is this about the other question [you linked from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41681784/why-do-i-not-need-to-escape-the-in-this-make-file) or is it something else entirely?