# What is the use of OR operator in dependency list?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I see a build rule like the following.

```
a: b c | d
    some_rule
```

For example:

```
result.xml: parser.py data0.txt | data1.txt
    python parser.py data0.txt data1.txt
```

So, I am wondering, how would the above be different if the OR operator "|" was not used at all. What is the use of an OR operator in dependency list?

Comment: For completeness sake: it's not an "or" operator, it's a notation for order-only dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
a regular prerequisite can lead to the target being rebuilt,
an order-only prerequisite doesn't force that

Long answer:
see this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24856711/10304821) also on SO

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is helpful.

Comment: Or the documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html