# Pattern rule with partial dependency

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a `makefile` with a bunch of `.R` scripts that create `.csv` files as output. These files are then used in a python simulation.

```
all: $(FILES)
  python simulation.py

$(FILES): %.csv: %.R 
  Rscript $<
```

This is straightforward. My wrinkle is that one (and only one) of the `.R` scripts has its own dependency, say `sourcedata`. It seems that placing this dependency in the pattern would be annoying

```
all: $(FILES)
  python simulation.py

$(FILES): %.csv: %.R sourcedata
  Rscript $<

sourcedata:
  wget "sourcedata.zip"
```

But doing it like `all: sourcedata $(FILES)` and relying on order-of-operations would [be less effective](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9160163/843419). I guess that I could also give that R file its own phony rule

```
problem_script.R: sourcedata
  @echo R script read
```

but I haven't been able to test if that will work. Is there an established way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, you need to specify that the particular CSV file needs to be rebuilt whenever *either* the R file *or* the `sourcedata` file changes, right?

If so, just add this:

```
problem_script.csv: sourcedata
```

(no recipe needed).  This declares an extra prerequisite for that particular CSV file, so whenever it's out of date with respect to `sourcedata` it will be rebuilt.

Comment: Yeah, I think you had it. I guess I didn't know that a single target could have two different recipes; would this work if the second recipe were non-empty? I can't think of what that would mean...

Comment: A target cannot have more than one recipe.  You'll get an error (except for double-colon rules).  However, you didn't declare a recipe, you just declared more prerequisites.  You can declare as many sets of prerequisites as you like for the same target: they're just appended together.