# What happens when we repeat make all command?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, dependencies, dependency-graph

I am trying to understand how makefiles work. This is a sample makefile:

```
all: prog
x.o: x.cpp globals.hh
    $(CC) -c x.cpp
y.o: y.cpp globals.hh
    $(CC) -c y.cpp
prog: x.o y.o
    $(LD) -o prog x.o y.o -lc
```

If I do `make file` and then make some changes in the `x.cpp`, and then repeat `make all` which commands are re-run?

From what I understand, the following commands will be re-run:

`$(CC) -c x.cpp`

and

`-o prog x.o y.o -lc`

And if I change the headers file instead, I think all three will re-run when I do make all again.

Am I correct? What would be the sequence?

Also, I am trying to understand how a dependency graph of a makefile could look like. I know that all, x.o, y.o and prog are targets here. But does my logic make sense?
[image]

Comment: Also see this as it might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9160175/708312

Comment: Did you read some [documention about `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) and about [the GCC compiler](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or your C++ compiler ?

Answer (score 0):

None will be re-run.

When creating `x.o`, `y.o`, and `prog`, each of those will be newer than their respective input files.

`make` does not remake files that are newer than their inputs, so no commands will be re-run.

From the [POSIX spec on `make`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html):

> ***EXTENDED DESCRIPTION***
>
> The make utility attempts to perform the actions required to ensure that the specified targets are up-to-date. A target shall be considered up-to-date if it exists and is newer than all of its dependencies, or if it has already been made up-to-date by the current invocation of make (regardless of the target's existence or age). A target may also be considered up-to-date if it exists, is the same age as one or more of its prerequisites, and is newer than the remaining prerequisites (if any). *The make utility shall treat all prerequisites as targets themselves and recursively ensure that they are up-to-date, processing them in the order in which they appear in the rule. The make utility shall use the modification times of files to determine whether the corresponding targets are out-of-date.*
>
> To ensure that a target is up-to-date, make shall ensure that all of the prerequisites of a target are up-to-date, then check to see if the target itself is up-to-date. If the target is not up-to-date, the target shall be made up-to-date by executing the rule's commands (if any). If the target does not exist after the target has been successfully made up-to-date, the target shall be treated as being newer than any target for which it is a prerequisite.
>
> If a target exists and there is neither a target rule nor an inference rule for the target, the target shall be considered up-to-date. It shall be an error if make attempts to ensure that a target is up-to-date but the target does not exist and there is neither a target rule nor an inference rule for the target.