# GNU make wildcard function doesn't find runtime generated files

Tags: function, makefile, wildcard, gnu, is-empty

**Summary:**
I'm using GNU Make (3.81) on a unix-like system and I've run into an issue where the `$(wildcard, pattern)` function is unable to find a file generated by a (presumably/apparently?) previously executed recipe, whereas other programs (e.g. ls) are able to verify its existence. I would like to know why the wildcard function is not returning anything, when it's expanded (to the empty string), and how I might get it to find the generated file.

**Test case:**
The following test case illustrates the problem.
Makefile contents:

```
.PHONY: build clean

test:
    @echo "Creating test file 'test'."
    @echo "this is a test file" > test

build: test
    @echo "Directory contents:"
    @ls
    @echo "Test file contents:"
    @cat test
    @echo "Wildcard output:"
    @echo $(wildcard test)

clean:
    @rm -f test
```

Running the makefile twice (then cleaning up) shows that only on the second run does it detect the created file.
Output:

```
Creating test file 'test'.
Directory contents:
makefile  test
Test file contents:
this is a test file
Wildcard output:

Directory contents:
makefile  test
Test file contents:
this is a test file
Wildcard output:
test
```

**To reproduce:**
Save the makefile in an empty directory, then run "make build;make build;make clean".

**Research:**
The order in which the prerequisites of a target are processed is [independent of the order in which they appear in the list after the colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647480), therefore explicit inter-prerequisite dependencies must be introduced if you want to define the order in which they're processed.

However, I don't think I can strip down the dependencies any more; `build` depends on `test`, and `test` corresponds to a file which doesn't exist and is generated by its recipe. I presumed it would be present by the time the recipe for `build` was to be processed.

From my knowledge of how make parses the makefile, the wildcard function inside the recipe should not be expanded until it's processed.
However, I clearly see a difference between the output of the built-in make functionality, and the output of common utilities accessed through the shell, so this presumption is probably wrong, but I haven't come across any good explanations of what's supposed to happen here, not even in the GNU make manual.

*N.B. The purpose of this question is simply to attain an understanding of the workings of the wildcard function relevant to this problem; there is a practical use case from which I distilled this watered down version, but I'm more interested in this case.*

Comment: It's been lot of time since your question, but still :) How did you finally "distilled this watered down version"?

Comment: GNU make 4.3 on a 2021 Linux distro, shows `test` under the first wildcard invocation as well, but I couldn't identify in the changelogs when the behavior changed. Under Windows 7, I saw your expected behavior using natively compiled GNU make 4.2.1 , and confirmed your observed behavior on 3.81. See bugs [443](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?443) and [21231](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?21231) on this, it may be an internal caching issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GNU make expands *all* of the commands for a target before executing *any* of them.  In this context, "expand" means "replace all variable references with their values (recursively), and evaluate any function references."  `$(wildcard)` is a function reference, of course.  Since the expansion occurs before any of the commands are executed, of course the file `test` cannot be found -- it hasn't been created yet.  The second time you run the build, `test` exists already, so `$(wildcard)` can find it.

Regarding your statement that the order in which prerequisites are processed:  *technically* GNU make makes no guarantees about the order, but *practically* speaking the prereqs are processed left-to-right, and despite attempts by purists to change that (for the sole purpose of screwing with people who haven't completely specified dependencies), the likelihood that GNU make will actually change that implementation detail is vanishingly small.  **However** you can only really rely on that ordering in a *serial* build.  If you run the build in parallel, then things get a bit trickier:  GNU make *does* still process the prereqs in left-to-right order, but it no longer waits for one to finish before starting the next, so in effect they may appear to be processed in random or "any" order, subject to the inter-prereq dependencies, which is why it's a good practice to specify the those dependencies.