# Makefile order of dependencies

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I was just handed a Makefile that has the following:

```
rpm: clean $(JARFILE)
    # commands here...
```

As you might have guessed, the `clean` target deletes the jar if it exists.  Is this Makefile correct?  Is there a guarantee that the `clean` target will be run before the `JARFILE` target?  I'm not asking about style, but correctness. Is there a chance the `JARFILE` will be built but then just blown away by the `clean` target?

I'm using gnu make so that's what I'm most interested in; I'm not sure if this is intended to be portable to other flavors of make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run make without any parallelism enabled (without `-j`) then your makefile will work properly.  Make does guarantee that prerequisites are built in the order that they're listed in the makefile, if they are run serially.

However if you enable `-j` then both targets will probably be run in parallel and then you could run into trouble.

Comment: _"Make does guarantee that prerequisites are built in the order that they're listed in the makefile, if they are run serially."_ - Is my understanding correct that this means something like _"[Make does guarantee that prerequisites are built in the order that they're listed in the makefile], **if the other rules of the Makefile allow that**"_? Also see [my answer to this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77176584/1562596) for some elaborations on this, and an example where other parts of the Makefile could cause `$(JARFILE)` to be built before the `clean` recipe is run.

Comment: What I mean is, if make considers the `rpm` target it will consider the prerequisites in the order they appear in the prerequisites list.  If they need to be built they will be built in that order.  If they don't need to be built, they won't be built.  If some other target that was already considered by make, already listed `$(JARFILE)` as a prerequisite, then it would have already been built as a result of that target and so it would not be rebuilt as a result of this target.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. Then, in the first Makefile example of my answer to this same question, the observed behaviour would be described as `make` first considering the leftmost prereq `clean`, to satisfy it builds `A.jar` after which the `clean` recipe can be executed, then moves on to the next prereq of `rpm` which is `A.jar`, notes that it has already been built and of course doesn't re-build it; then, with all prereqs of `rpm` satisfied, `make` runs the `rpm` recipe. In summary, `make` will have run the recipes for the targets `A.jar`, `clean`, `rpm`, in that order.

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a guarantee that the clean target will be run before the JARFILE target?

**`make` in general**: no, there is [no such guarantee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1647612/1562596).

**GNU `make`**:

- if there's a reason to resolve prerequisites in some certain order, that order will be used
- otherwise they will be resolved left-right [1]

For your specific rule, with the prereqs `clean $(JARFILE)`, it isn't likely that the rest of the Makefile describes a dependency tree that gives GNU make a reason to resolve `$(JARFILE)` before `clean`.

It is possible in theory though. E.g. consider this `Makefile`:

```makefile
# --- file: Makefile ---

rpm: clean A.jar
    @$(rpm_build)

A.jar: A.java
    cp $^ $@
    @printf "[done: '$@']\n\n"

clean: A.jar
    @# Error msg if attempting to delete non-existing file, so I
    @# I made sure it will exist before rm-ing it by adding A.jar
    @# as a prerequisite to `clean` above. //consultant
    rm A.jar
    @printf "[done: '$@']\n\n"


rpm_build = @[ -e $(JARFILE) ] && echo "rpm: OK." \
                               || echo "rpm: ERR: no '$(JARFILE)'"
```

Try to make the `rpm` target:

```bash
$ touch A.java
$ gmake

cp A.java A.jar
[done: 'A.jar']

rm A.jar
[done: 'clean']

rpm: ERR: no 'A.jar'
```

The dependency graph of `Makefile` is resolved by building `A.jar`, then doing `clean`, then building `rpm`. With this, all prereqs are honored - *GNU make* was not at fault for the company's build system breaking down due to the failing `rpm` target (someone else was).

---

### A better option

It's a good idea to handle any restrictions on in what order prereqs are resolved through the *dependency graph*. This is clearer (not everyone knows about GNU make's intricacies), makes the Makefile (more) portable, and is more robust [2].

Below is an example. I added the intermediate target `A_clean_jar` so we still have the possibility of building `A.jar` without first triggering a `clean`.

```makefile
# --- file: Makefile ---

rpm: A_clean_jar
    @$(inspect_jar)

A_clean_jar: A.java clean
    $(build_jar)
    @printf '[done: created pristine jar]\n\n'

A.jar: A.java
    $(build_jar)
    @printf '[done: created jar]\n\n'
    
clean:
    @rm -f A.jar
    @printf '[done: jar cleaned out of existence]\n\n'


build_jar = cp A.java A.jar

inspect_jar = @[ -e A.jar ] && printf "rpm: OK.\n\n" \
                            || printf "rpm: ERR: no 'A.jar'\n\n"
```

Let's try:

```bash
$ touch A.java
$ gmake rpm

[done: jar cleaned out of existence]

cp A.java A.jar
[done: created pristine jar]

rpm: OK.


$ # so: first `clean`, then build A.jar, then the rpm target - all well.

$ # now: build target A.jar - no preceding `clear` expected:

$ touch A.java
$ gmake A.jar

cp A.java A.jar
[done: created jar]

$ # check.
```

---

### [2] What about the "robustness" benefits mentioned earlier?

*A few months later, the CTO glanced over the repos after noticing a slight increase in the data center bills. A commit caught his eye, issued by some test engineer of a seemingly unrelated department, supposedly maintaining the intranet legacy PHP and sometimes helping out the secretary of the accounting assistant with Excel scripts. Recognizing the commit was made to the same file that was involved in the build system havoc some time ago, causing an expensive delay of an upcoming launch event, he had a look - and found this:*

```makefile
#clean
clean: A.jar
    @# Added back my `clean: A.jar` above - this time I tested it
    @# before pushing, and now nothing crashed. // your guy
    rm A.jar
    @# rm -f A.jar  (avoid -f with rm - dangerous)
    @printf "[done: '$@']\n\n"
```

*Some moments later, a colleague of the CTO noticed this on his screen:*

```bash
$ # let's just see how this behaves
$ gmake

java.c A.java && jar cvf A.jar A.class
[done: created jar]

[done: jar cleaned out of existence]

java.c A.java && jar cvf A.jar A.class
[done: created pristine jar]

rpm: OK.

$ less Makefile

$ git revert HEAD -m "reverting: prev. commit caused an unneccessary "\
"build (jar created twice), but nothing worse than that this time"

$ git log -2 --pretty=format:'%ae'
deadlockDennis@consultants.spacex.com

$ gh api -X DELETE /repos/admin/spacex-padctrl-prod/collaborators/deadlockDennis@consultants.spacex.com

$ >> ~/notesToSelf.txt echo 'avoid long-duration consultant contracts'
```

---

**footnotes**

[1] at least that's what's indicated by [MadScientist's other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41007364/1562596) (he is the maintainer of GNU make)